# Did Japan have secret films about going into the US in the 40s?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military, japan, aircraft

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gOE70M9Lno) film (narrated by Ronald Regan) was produced in the 40s. It discusses detailed planning for an air mission into an area in Japan.

Did Japan have similar fims in the time period to aid them in any missions to the US?

Comment: 1) How to prove a negative? 2) Japan had no plans to invade the continental U.S. for the same reason that Rule 2 on Page 1 of the *Rules of Warfare for European Nations* (after Bernard Montgomery) is: "***Don't fight in Asia with your land armies.***"

Comment: Since Japan did not plan any large scale air raid on the continental US, why would have? Also, producing movies takes time, effort etc so it is not a very efficient way of disseminating information for one-time attacks like Pearl Harbour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcv1cWtsH_c) is the film JIA made after they attacked Pearl Harbor and Malaysia ( including **much of propaganda** but including the real footages ( even to me hard to tell )).

Unfortunately, Hawaii ( or Midway ) is the closest U.S soil Japanese was able to advance or attack. If the "colonies of the U.S in the 40's" are O.K, then,

**[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8a1D_WbnB0)** is the film made by the Japanese Imperial Army then about the attack on the [**Corregidor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corregidor) ( and the advancement and the propaganda until there ), then the U.S's territory in 1942. This would be probably the **most** direct answer to you, 1) made by Japanese "secretly", 2) Against the "U.S" soil, 3)in the 40's. 4) On the premise "negative" connotes any attack on the U.S soil.

Comment: The authentication of my answer will not be verified until you master Japanese....